# Array Merge in For [PHP]

Tags: php, arrays, merge, push

X times `for` process is done. New array data is added each time `for`prcess.

```
 $input_array = array("success"=>true ,'ab' => 2,'def' => 1);

for ($i = 0; $i <= 6;$i++) {
    $data = [
        'lg_' . $i => 'LG: T-' . $i
    ];
    $arrayMerging = array_merge($input_array, $data);
}

print_r($arrayMerging);
```

> Array ([success] => true, [ab] => 2 [def] => 1 [leg_6] => LG: T-6)

It just adds the last part (6). The sections `1,2,3,4,5` do not exist in the array. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you're only seeing the last key in the loop is that the result/accumulator array (`$arrayMerging`) is never assigned, so you're starting from scratch on every iteration.

You probably meant something like:

```
<?php

$input_array = ["success" => true ,'ab' => 2,'def' => 1];
$arrayMerging = $input_array;

for ($i = 0; $i <= 6; $i++) {
    $data = ["lg_$i" => 'LG: T-' . $i];
    $arrayMerging = array_merge($arrayMerging, $data);
}

print_r($arrayMerging);
```

or clearer as:

```
<?php

$input_array = ["success" => true , "ab" => 2, "def" => 1];
$merged = $input_array;

for ($i = 0; $i <= 6; $i++) {
    $merged["lg_$i"] = "LG: T-$i";
}

print_r($merged);
```

where we assign properties directly.

Output:

```
Array
(
    [success] => 1
    [ab] => 2
    [def] => 1
    [lg_0] => LG: T-0
    [lg_1] => LG: T-1
    [lg_2] => LG: T-2
    [lg_3] => LG: T-3
    [lg_4] => LG: T-4
    [lg_5] => LG: T-5
    [lg_6] => LG: T-6
)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are not merging the *result* back into the final array. Try this:

```
$input_array = array("success"=>true ,'ab' => 2,'def' => 1);

for ($i = 0; $i <= 6;$i++) {
    $data = [
        'lg_' . $i => 'LG: T-' . $i
    ];
    $input_array = array_merge($input_array, $data);
}

print_r($input_array);
```

Another example: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/052c3edaca2e8ac7b819201eb5bb3b61d384bca5

Answer (score 0):

DO it this way with `array_push`,

```
<?php
$input_array = array("success"=>true ,'ab' => 2,'def' => 1);

for ($i = 0; $i <= 6;$i++) {
    $data = [
        'lg_' . $i => 'LG: T-' . $i
    ];
    array_push($input_array, $data);
}

print_r($input_array);
?>
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/CImYY

As per comment:

```
<?php
$input_array = array("success"=>true ,'ab' => 2,'def' => 1);

for ($i = 0; $i <= 6;$i++) {
    $data = [
        'lg_' . $i => 'LG: T-' . $i
    ];
  $input_array = array_merge($input_array, $data); // see this line
}

  print_r($input_array);
?>
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/R57v6